# Where does a distributor gets it's power from?

Tags: engine, gmc, suburban

I have a 1996 GMC K2500 Suburban with a 7.4 liter engine not getting power. Where does the distributor get it's power from?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on which power you're talking about. Here is an image of a distributor which would go into your truck:

[image]

The plug which is pointing right at you provides power for the electronics inside the distributor (green box). This is low voltage power. To power the spark plugs, the distributor is powered from a coil through the cap. The connection for that is on the right hand side (red arrow). This is the high voltage power.

Comment: the coil also has an ignitor (driver) on this engine. everything is powered by the eng-1 fuse in the underhood fuse block.